# how to optimize parameters of of the support vector machine by using the genetic algorithm with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm

In order to learn the support vector machine, we must determine various parameters.

For example, there are parameters such as cost and gamma.

I am trying to determine sigma and gamma parameters of SVM Using "GA" package and "kernlab" package of R.

I use accuracy as the evaluation function of the genetic algorithm.

I have created the following code, and I ran it.

```
library(GA) 
library(kernlab) 
data(spam) 
index <- sample(1:dim(spam)[1]) 
spamtrain <- spam[index[1:floor(dim(spam)[1]/2)], ] 
spamtest <- spam[index[((ceiling(dim(spam)[1]/2)) + 1):dim(spam)[1]], ] 

f <- function(x) 
{ 
x1 <- x[1] 
x2 <- x[2] 
filter <- ksvm(type~.,data=spamtrain,kernel="rbfdot",kpar=list(sigma=x1),C=x2,cross=3) 
mailtype <- predict(filter,spamtest[,-58]) 
t <- table(mailtype,spamtest[,58]) 
return(t[1,1]+t[2,2])/(t[1,1]+t[1,2]+t[2,1]+t[2,2]) 
} 

GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", fitness = f, min = c(-5.12, -5.12), max = c(5.12, 5.12), popSize = 50, maxiter = 2) 
summary(GA) 
plot(GA)
```

However, When I call the GA function,the following error is returned.

"No Support Vectors found. You may want to change your parameters"

I can not understand why the code is bad.

Comment: If you only have two parameters to optimise, you don't really need a GA. Define a grid of plausible values, and test your model's fit over the grid.

Comment: Hello, Hong Ooi!
Thank you for the reply immediately.
The above code is an ad hoc example .
I plan to use my own custom kernel for svm finally.
I plan to use five or six parameters for svm.
If I use the grid search, the number of combinations is enormous.
So, I want to use GA to optimize parameters.

Comment: Are you sure that negative values for `sigma` and `C` are meaningful?

Comment: Hey, Vincent Zoonekynd! Thank you for kind reply. I am sorry. The above settings of values are incomplete. I gave as an example of code only. I will specify the exact values for the actual analysis.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I am sure they are **not**.

Comment: Hey, everyone!
After I explore the optimal parameters roughly with grid search,
I think I will carry out the optimization with Nelder-Mead method.
(giving the optimum value of the grid search to the initial values ​​of the parameters of Nelder-Mead method) 
I have also confirmed that the following command to work properly.

optim(c(0.2, 0.5), f, control=list(fnscale=-1)) #The initial value is irresponsible

Everyone, thank you for the support!

Comment: I think that in the fitness function for GA you should perform a k-fold crossvalidation on the training set. The f function given above will optimize the parameters for the given test set, which is normally not the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Using GA for SVM parameters is not a good idea - it should be sufficient to just do a regular grid search ( two for loops, one for `C` and one for `gamma` values).

In Rs library `e1071 (which also provides SVMs) there is a method`tune.svm` which looks for best parameters using a grid search.

**Example**

```
data(iris)
obj <- tune.svm(Species~., data = iris, sampling = "fix", 
gamma = 2^c(-8,-4,0,4), cost = 2^c(-8,-4,-2,0))
plot(obj, transform.x = log2, transform.y = log2)
plot(obj, type = "perspective", theta = 120, phi = 45)
```

Which also shows one important thing - you should look for a good C and gamma values in a geometric manner, so eg. `2^x` for `x` in `{-10,-8,-6,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4}`.

GA is an algorithm for meta optimisation, where the parameters space is huge, and there is no easy correlation between parameters and the optimising function. It requires tuning of much more parameters then SVM (number of generations, size of the population, mutation probability, crossing probability, mutation operator, crossing operator ...) so it completely useless approach here.

And of course - as it was earlier stated in comments - C and Gamma **have to** be strictly positive.

For more details about using `e1071` take a look at the CRAN document: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf